# Android sensor accuracy

Tags: android, sensors, calibration

I made an android app that relies heavily on very accurate sensor data (magnetometer, gravitymeter and accelerometer). To achieve this I validate all these device sensors periodically for highest quality of service by checking the sensor status for SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH. If one of these sensors doesn't have this status I show a calibration screen until the high accuracy can be delivered. On my own device this is working perfectly fine, but I get a lot of app reviews from people who can't get around my calibration screen. My question is, can I rely that every android device is per se capable of delivering SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH or do I have to lower the minimum accuracy? If so, how is this status even defined cross devices?

Comment: you neither can be sure that every device will ever return you `SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH`, nor that the accuracy is really high. Android devices do not have good sensors to provide you with accurate data, as the mobile phone/tablet just does not need them and they are too expensive . If you want high accuracy data, you need to use specialized devices, not mobile phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.  And even if you could, its possible for the sensor to be broken and returning the high status incorrectly.  And you don't know if OEM A and OEM B have the same definition of high.  In the end, you're trusting the individual hardware drivers for each device, and hoping all of them are both acting in good faith and had the same definition of "high accuracy".  Neither of which are really reliable.

Comment: Ok thanks, I feared it would be like this, the whole sensor business under Android is a real nightmare compared to iOS. If the sensors were broken I would be fine when the users can't access the app, because if they could access it it would not be a good experience for them anyways. But the different definitions for high between manufacturers is a bummer.

Comment: @chris That's the difference between a single device made by a single manufacturer, and an OS that can be used by a variety of manufacturers.  You'd see the same types of problems on Windows or Linux.  Life becomes easier when you control the hardware and the software.  Of course then the user loses a lot of choice, which isn't great either.